# Decoding an MKA audio file into raw data (MKA Audio to raw audio data)

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, decode

My task is to open an existing audio file with the **`mka`** extension ([Matroska](https://www.matroska.org/index.html) container) and extract the raw audio data. [This](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/decode_audio_8c-example.html) example shows only an example of extracting raw data from an **`mp2`** file. I do not know how to do this with the **`mka`** container. I would like to have something like this:

**UPD**

**I found** an option to save audio data in the format in which it was recorded in the audio file. An example is shown below.

**PS. This is only a test version and most likely there are memory leaks and other problems.**

```cpp
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include "audiodecoder.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AudioDecoder decoder("/home/test/test.mka");
    bool started = decoder.start();
    if (!started) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    QFile file("/home/test/rawData.bin");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    while (true) {
        auto data = decoder.getData(255);
        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        file.write(data.data(), data.size());
    }
    file.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**audiodecoder.h**

```cpp
class AudioDecoder {
public:
    AudioDecoder(const QString& fileName);
    AudioDecoder& operator=(const AudioDecoder& rhs) = delete;
    AudioDecoder& operator=(AudioDecoder&& rhs) = delete;
    AudioDecoder(const AudioDecoder& rhs) = delete;
    AudioDecoder(AudioDecoder&& rhs) = delete;
    virtual ~AudioDecoder(void);

    virtual bool start(void) noexcept;
    virtual QByteArray getData(const quint16& size) noexcept;
    virtual bool stop(void) noexcept;

protected:
    bool m_initialized;
    QString m_fileName;

    AVFrame* p_frame = nullptr;
    AVPacket* p_packet = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* p_cdcCtx = nullptr;
    AVFormatContext* p_frmCtx = nullptr;
};
```

**audiodecoder.cpp**

```cpp
static void logging(const char* message)
{
    qDebug() << message;
}

AudioDecoder::AudioDecoder(const QString& fileName)
    : m_initialized(false)
    , m_fileName(fileName)
    , p_cdcCtx(nullptr)
    , p_frmCtx(nullptr)
{
    av_register_all();
}

QByteArray AudioDecoder::getData(const quint16& dataSize) noexcept
{
    QByteArray data;
    qint32 response = 0;
    if (av_read_frame(p_frmCtx, p_packet) >= 0) {
        //logging(QString("AVPacket->pts %1").arg(p_packet->pts).toStdString().c_str());
        //response = decode_packet(p_packet, p_cdcCtx, p_frame);
        response = avcodec_send_packet(p_cdcCtx, p_packet);
        if (response < 0) {
            logging("Error while sending a packet to the decoder");
            return {};
        }
        while (response >= 0) {
            response = avcodec_receive_frame(p_cdcCtx, p_frame);
            if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
                break;
            }
            else if (response < 0) {
                logging("Error while receiving a frame from the decoder");
                return {};
            }
            if (response >= 0) {
                logging(QString("Frame %1 (type=%2, size=%3 bytes) pts %4 key_frame %5 [DTS %6], duration[%7]")
                            .arg(p_cdcCtx->frame_number)
                            .arg(av_get_picture_type_char(p_frame->pict_type))
                            .arg(p_frame->pkt_size)
                            .arg(p_frame->pts)
                            .arg(p_frame->key_frame)
                            .arg(p_frame->coded_picture_number)
                            .arg(p_frame->pkt_duration)
                            .toStdString()
                            .c_str());

                for (int i = 0; i < p_frame->linesize[0]; ++i) {
                    data.push_back(p_frame->data[0][i]);
                }
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(p_packet);
        return data;
    }
    return {};
}

bool AudioDecoder::start(void) noexcept
{
    if (m_initialized) {
        return true;
    }

    int error;
    // Open the input file to read from it.
    if ((error = avformat_open_input(&p_frmCtx,
             m_fileName.toStdString().c_str(), nullptr, nullptr))
        < 0) {
        qDebug() << "Could not open input file: " << m_fileName;
        p_frmCtx = nullptr;
        return false;
    }
    // Get information on the input file (number of streams etc.).
    if ((error = avformat_find_stream_info(p_frmCtx, nullptr)) < 0) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        qDebug() << __LINE__;
        return false;
    }
    // Make sure that there is only one stream in the input file.
    if ((p_frmCtx)->nb_streams != 1) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        qDebug() << __LINE__;
        return false;
    }

    if (p_frmCtx->streams[0]->codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        qDebug() << __LINE__;
        return false;
    }

    // Find a decoder for the audio stream.
    AVCodec* input_codec = nullptr;
    if (!(input_codec = avcodec_find_decoder((p_frmCtx)->streams[0]->codecpar->codec_id))) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        qDebug() << __LINE__;
        return false;
    }
    // Allocate a new decoding context.
    AVCodecContext* avctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(input_codec);
    if (!avctx) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        qDebug() << __LINE__;
        return false;
    }
    // Initialize the stream parameters with demuxer information.
    error = avcodec_parameters_to_context(avctx, (p_frmCtx)->streams[0]->codecpar);
    if (error < 0) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        avcodec_free_context(&avctx);
        qDebug() << __LINE__;
        return false;
    }
    /* Open the decoder for the audio stream to use it later. */
    if ((error = avcodec_open2(avctx, input_codec, NULL)) < 0) {
        avcodec_free_context(&avctx);
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        qDebug() << __LINE__;
        return false;
    }
    /* Save the decoder context for easier access later. */
    p_cdcCtx = avctx;
    av_dump_format(p_frmCtx, 0, m_fileName.toStdString().c_str(), 0);

    p_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!p_frame) {
        logging("failed to allocated memory for AVFrame");
        return false;
    }
    p_packet = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!p_packet) {
        logging("failed to allocated memory for AVPacket");
        return false;
    }
    return m_initialized = true;
}

bool AudioDecoder::stop(void) noexcept
{
    if (p_cdcCtx != nullptr) {
        avcodec_free_context(&p_cdcCtx);
    }
    if (p_frmCtx != nullptr) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
    }
    return true;
}

AudioDecoder::~AudioDecoder(void)
{
    stop();
}
```

But the problem in this example is that I didn't implement the ability to get exactly the requested size of audio data. In my case, it's just ignored.

Comment: You'll have to give us a little more to go on. What is your specific question?

Comment: @metal, I want to open any audio file of any extension. After that, I want to extract the audio data from this audio file and save it to a temporary buffer for further work. I want to extract audio data based on a certain size of the requested data. For example, in my case, I will need to request 1000 bytes of audio data from a file ( in my case, this is the pcm_alaw type of audio data) and process them. After processing them, you need to request the next 1000 bytes, and so on, until I read the entire file.

Comment: Very good. Now what is it that you are stuck on in that algorithm? We won't write your program or google tutorials for you, but if you're tripped up by some particular piece of the puzzle, we're here to help. You just need a more specific question.

Comment: @metal, I updated my question. I have a problem with how to implement getting a certain size of data and writing to `QByteArray`.

Comment: @metal, At the moment, I understand that the data itself (in my case, `pcm_alaw`) is in **`AVPacket::buf`**, which outputs `avcodec_receive_packet`. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract audio data encoded in the format in which you get it from an audio file, then You should view [this](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcode_aac_8c-example.html) example. In this example, you will need to change the output type from `acc` to `alaw`. The compressed stream will be in [AVPacket::buf](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVBufferRef.html):

> A reference to the reference-counted buffer where the packet data is stored.

I also recommend viewing [this](https://steemit.com/programming/@targodan/decoding-audio-files-with-ffmpeg) article. It will help you :)